# performSegueWithIdentifier and viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

MainViewController:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNextVC sender:self];
```

Segue destination controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"Show text!");
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSignUp" sender:self]; }
```

Why doesn't the code from the destination controller's viewDidLoad method execute?

Comment: edit the question and add the error displaied in the log: "view not loaded in the window hierarchy". PKP replied with the correct solution.

Comment: Does the 1st segue work?

Comment: You should call performSegue... call in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

viewDidLoad is called when the ViewController object is created loading nib file. It is not yet attached to the window. You should call performSegue... call in viewDidAppear.

Finally, If you are calling performSegue directly without any action being performed. I'd suggest you take a look at the flow again.

Comment: So is the viewDidLoad method called only for the initial scene of the storyboard?

Comment: No. It is called for every ViewController when it is created. (when you do this: [[ViewController alloc] initWithNib:] and is created successfully). And in this case it is called internally when you are preparing for Segue

Comment: So, I performSegue... then the destinationViewController allocs and initswithnib and after that the viewDidLoad method executes. Am I right?

Comment: Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted. I get this

Comment: Are you pushing new segue in viewWillAppear of viewDidAppear? It is difficult to guess the problem without knowing the context. Why don't you push the second viewController directly if all you are doing in first viewController is push the second one without any operation?

Answer (score 0):

if you copied and pasted I'd assume it's because you're missing a " which the compiler should've warned you about

if the " is there try an NSLog in your prepare for segue and see if it's getting called

Comment: also if not check your segue identifier in storyboard and make sure they match

Comment: It shows the destination controller in my simulator, so the segue is working fine, it's just the viewdidload method of the destination that doesn't execute? I don't understand why.. ( i checked the storyboard identifiers, everything is ok there )

Comment: try setting the view as the initial view controller and see if it gets called also make sure you have the correct storyboard class for that controller

Comment: if load view is called then viewdidload should always be called. if that view is loading without loading the class you will not get notified though